# Creating linearGradient fails

Tags: javascript, html, svg, google-closure-library

I'm writing a plugin for a bigger application which is in HTML5.

The plugin contains a svg which displays relations. I would like to add linearGradients to the svg, but that doesn't quite work because the output tags are in lower cases 'lineargradient' instead of 'linearGradient'. I already tried to add the namespace to the svg element, but that didn't help.

Also created an extra document object with svg Doctype and namespace. The tags were now correct, but in that way I won't get the linearGradient object to the plugin in the html5 document object.

The problem seems to be the document.createElement function, which is called when creating a linearGradient object. It formats the tag to lowercase if the tag is not in the namespace
Is there any way to create a working linearGradient?

**Edit:**
I also tried to use document.importNode and document.adoptNode to import/adopt a node that I created with a SVG Document, but they seem to use the createElement function, as the important tag 'linearGradient' ist still written lowercase and though not working.

Comment: Have you tried [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS)?

Comment: The problem is that the build in linearGradient object in the google closure library calls createElement. So you can't replace that one.  
But I have tried that in a seperate snippet of code and had the same wrong result.